# Generating random int with specific condition C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, random

Consider some special condition, where we want to generate location data with some random speed.

```
public class Location
{
     public double Lat { get; set; }    
     public double Lng { get; set; }
     public int Speed { get; set; }
     public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

The speed can be randomly generated using **`Random.Next()`** method.
Now consider that we are going to have limit of **1 to 200** for speed,
and we want that most of the **`Random.Next(1,200)`** result be more likely at the rang of 1 to 120
(for example if we have 160 locations, most of the location speeds be at around 1 to 120(about 60% to 80% of the location) and the rest be at about range of 120 to 200)

I know some bad and ugly ways where you can divide your locations randomly into two list of locations and then generate speed separately for those lists, but I'm looking for a better and more efficient way.

Thanks!

Edit :
I have to mention that there is a property called
Date which is Type of **`DateTime`** and defines the time of a locations occurrence.
A list of location that is going to be generated will be a path so the speeds being generated should be relative to locations and time to just seem right(for example 2 continues locations can't have 2 unrelative speed like first location : 80KM/h , second location: 140 KM/h in a short time span of 30 seconds) so just the speed, date time and location should seem logically a normal path.

Answer (score 3):

Can't you just use two random numbers? The first to determine which range, and the second to choose a number in the appropriate range?

```
Random rng = new Random(); // This should only be created once, somewhere.

double proportionInLowerRange = 0.7;

int speed;

if (rng.NextDouble() <= proportionInLowerRange)
    speed = rng.Next(1, 121);
else
    speed = rng.Next(120, 201);
```

Note: The probabilities are linear across both ranges, so if you wanted a normal distribution this wouldn't work.

Comment: this works fine in some case, but in mine, the locations are relative and using such if condition has some chance that you have 2 location that are after each other but the speeds are not correct(for example it jumps out from 80 km/h to 110 km/h in less 10 10 secs, which does not seems right) and btw there is another parameter called Date which is a date time that defines the time each location occurred(I'm going to edit the question and add this so the question be more clear). so the time matters here and speeds are relative with time.